# linearlayout over a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, android-linearlayout

I have a dashboard in my app which is created with a gridview.
The first time the user launches the app I want to show some tooltips over the gridView. How can I place some linearlayout over the gridview?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your gridview inside a [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) or a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) as these allow views to overlap. Then you can place and position your LinearLayout in the same layout and it will appear over the gridwiew.

Comment: i solved with this solution. The only problem is that the buttons in the gridView are clickable when I have the overlay view, how can i disable the gridView?

Comment: You can either disable the onItemClickListener of the gridview when the tooltips are showing, or create an invisible view filling the entire screen that is clickable between the tooltips and the grid to solve that.